# Why didn't Fumio Kishida and Shigeru Ishiba give up in the LDP leadership election?

Tags: parties, japan, political-leaders

Most of candidates was declined, like Tarō Asō and Tomomi Inada. Why Kishida and Ishiba wasn't declined? It is because of the rule of Liberal-Democratic Party, or other candidates gave up?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the question and what specifically you're asking. It might help if you include a link to an English language article discussing this occurrence. Then we might be able to help clarify and answer this question

Comment: I *think* you are asking for the motivations of Kishida and Ishiba to continue running although Suda was supported by the vast majority of LDP officials. Is that correct? If so, the question may be off-topic because we cannot reasonably source the internal motivations of politicians.